# DynamoDB removals and updates when streaming data to S3 in Parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, parquet, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We have created a quick proof-of-concept to stream the changes in a DynamoDB table to a Lambda function. This function does some basic ETL-processing and puts records on a Firehose. This Firehose writes Parquet files to S3, for some Athena querying. This works extremely well and easy for inserts, but I was wondering if there are tips or best practices for dealing with removals or updates.

I remember vaguely from a past conference that some people run batch jobs to compact the data and delete marked data, but I cannot find any details on this. Change Data Capture is another term, but I've yet to see clear examples of this. Is there a way of dealing with updates in this streaming setup?

UPDATE: I might have phrased my question poorly since a lot of the focus is going to S3. I'm really looking for a flow to process the incoming removals and updates in the DynamoDB stream, save them somewhere and then periodically update the Parquet file to reflect these updates and removals. Maybe some compaction will be needed as well, but that's "nice to have" at this stage in my experiment.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to update your parquet files in s3, when your dynamodb records get changed/deleted?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to deal with the changed and deleted records in DynamoDB when using streams to S3 Parquet.

Comment: S3 is object storage, not a file system. You can't just edit files in it. You need to download it first, edit as you want, and fully replace. This requires fully custom solution, and this is not something that firehose can do for you.

Comment: I am fully aware that S3 is readonly and that you can't just update records in a Parquet file. My question is not focused on S3: I'm looking for a flow to deal with processing the removals and updates in the DynamoDB stream.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood by your question is that you want to deal with files on s3 and hence I would suggest you to use AWS Glue. you can create jobs as per your requirements.

If you use an Amazon S3 bucket as your data source, AWS Glue Studio detects the schema of the data at the specified location from one of the files, or by using the file you specify as a sample file.

Please refer to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/edit-jobs-source-s3-files.html

Also refer to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simplify-amazon-dynamodb-data-extraction-and-analysis-by-using-aws-glue-and-amazon-athena/

Comment: We've looked at Glue before, but we're looking for a "near realtime" architecture.

Comment: Ok then I would suggest you to use AWS Lambda

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth considering `S3 versioning` here too. If you do that, in your event message structure [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html), the `s3.object.version` key will exist. That way you'll be able to see if the entry was an edit or create, and for deletes you would look at: `eventName`. Otherwise you could have a system whereby you will only do a HTTP Post for creates, and PUTs for updates as that is also indicated in the `eventName`

If those options don't work for you, you would have to implement your own mechanism for detecting if the `PUT` was a new object or not, and this is system dependent how to do this. It may be best using `S3 metadata`, maybe it's easier in your own system, or using a table `DynamoDB` it really depends.